# Is it possible to enable by default the sound in amp-story?

Tags: amp-html, amp-stories

didn't find a way to enable by default the sound in an AMP Story.
Is it possible ?
Thanks

Comment: what happens if you include background-audio? That's the only AMP property related to sounds.

Comment: @noogui This is what I'm using. What I'm trying to to is to activate the sound, by default it's on mute and you have to unmute with the icon on the page.

Comment: ok, there's no indicated method to do that. Honestly, I think it's part of the design policy.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible to enable audio by default.  Browsers often explicitly blacklist this behavior and only allow audio to be enabled after a user gesture, e.g:

- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes
- https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/

The global muted state of an `amp-story` starts off muted; users must always unmute the story for audio to play out.