# Weird sound behavior in AMP-story

Tags: amp-html, amp-stories

I looked in stackoverflow and since this is an experimental technology, there is not much talk about it anywhere on the internet.

The story I created has several youtube videos as backgrounds, in `fill` grid layers. When the first one starts, it never stops, overlapping the audio with the next, and so on.

The thing is, I can't reproduce the issue on my work computer and neither on my phone (tested with chrome and firefox on both devices) because I can't find the audio button to turn it on. And it seems that [there is no way to turn it on by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775292/is-it-possible-to-enable-by-default-the-sound-in-amp-story).

Now I'm not even sure this button ever existed, but I remember seeing it 15 days ago when I created my first amp story. *EDIT: I saw the button on another computer with chrome 64. I have version 65.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`amp-youtube` is not yet supported as a child of `amp-story-grid-layer`.  The full list of supported children can be found in the [`amp-story-grid-layer` validation spec](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-story/validator-amp-story.protoascii#L289-L374).

The audio control is currently only present on stories that have audio through one of the supported mechanisms (an `amp-audio`/`amp-video` tag, or the `background-audio` attribute).

Comment: Thanks! We'll probably use `amp-video`. I think this could be better documented, though

Comment: This is also documented in the `amp-story-grid-layer` documentation here: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-story#children-(of-amp-story-grid-layer)